# jQuery Animation Triggered By User Interaction Depends on Previous Animation Completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I have a timeline that can be zoomed by clicking a `zoom in` or `zoom out` button. This timeline doesn't all fit on the screen at once, so it is a scrollable div. When the user clicks to zoom, I want the position in the timeline to be the same, so I calculate a new `scrollTop` for the scrollable div. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
var self = this;
...
this.zoomIn = function() {
    var offset = $("#scrollable").scrollTop();
    self.increaseZoomLevel(); // Assume this sets the correct zoom level
    var newOffset = offset * self.zoomLevel();
    $("#scrollable").scrollTop(newOffset);
};
```

This works fine. Now I'd like to animate the scrolling. This *almost* works:

```
var self = this;
...
this.zoomIn = function() {
    var offset = $("#scrollable").scrollTop();
    self.increaseZoomLevel(); // Assume this sets the correct zoom level
    var newOffset = offset * self.zoomLevel();
    $("#scrollable").animate({ scrollTop: newOffset });
};
```

It works if it's clicked once. However, if a second call to `zoomIn` happens while the animation is still running, the `newOffset` calculation is wrong because the offset is set to `scrollTop()` before `scrollTop()` is correct since the animation is still manipulating it.

I've tried to use jQuery's queue in various ways to make this calculation happen first, and that seems to work sometimes:

```
var self = this;
...
this.zoomIn = function() {
    $("#scrollable").queue(function(next) {
        var offset = $("#scrollable").scrollTop();
        self.increaseZoomLevel(); // Assume this sets the correct zoom level
        var newOffset = offset * self.zoomLevel();
        next();
    }).animate({ scrollTop: newOffset });
};
```

I think I'm just not understanding `queue` properly. How do I keep everything in order even when zoomIn is called repeatedly and rapidly? I want:

`zoomIn` x 2 clicks

to give me:

calculate 1 -> animate 1 start -> animate 1 finish -> calculate 2 -> animate 2 start -> animate 2 finish

and not

calculate 1 -> animate 1 start -> calculate 2 -> animate 1 finish -> animate 2 start -> animate 2 finish

Because then animate 2 is based on incorrect calculations.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend using a boolean flag, to see if you're currently animating or not, and then queue the next calculation until the boolean is false again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "and then queue the next calculation until the boolean is false again"? I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I very much appreciate the answers given. They both would work, but my unwritten requirements included animations that completed entirely as well as no loss of clicks. I know, I should have been more thorough in my question.

Anyway, I believe I have a solution that fits both of those requirements using jQuery queues. There were a couple of things I didn't realize about queues that I learned that got me going in the right direction. The biggest thing is this from the jQuery `.animate` docs:

> When a custom queue name is used the animation does not automatically
>   start...

This allowed me to have complete control over the queue. I believe this is similar to (or maybe exactly what) @RobinJonsson's comment meant.

```
var top = 0;
var animating = false;

function calcAndAnimate(top) {
    $("#block").queue("other", function() {
        // Calculations go here
        animating = true;
        // This kicks off the next animation
        $("#block").dequeue("other");
    });
    $("#block").animate({
        top: top
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        queue: "other",
        complete: function () {
            animating = false;
            // No need; it looks like animate dequeues for us, which makes sense.
            // So the next calculation will be kicked off for us.
            //$("#block").dequeue("other");
        }
    });
}

$("#queueButton").click(function() {
    top += 20;
    calcAndAnimate(top);
    if (!animating) {
        // Initial animation, need to kick it off
        $("#block").dequeue("other");
    }
});
```

There's a working example with log messages showing the enforced order at http://jsfiddle.net/cygnl7/6h3c2/3/

Comment: The only problem here is that the animate block captures "top" before the calculation block runs, so calculations won't apply to the animation. So I have a chicken or egg here... If I put the animate block after the calculation has run (i.e., inside the calculation block), it can get out of order. If I put it outside the calculation block, it captures the wrong value. Can the value to be animated take a function?

Comment: The way I got around the calculation dependency was to put the `animate` block in its own function() that gets added to the `other` queue just like the calculation block. This allowed me to read the current calculations inside of the `animate` block instead of capturing the old value in a closure. I then took the `animate()` call out of the `other` queue since I wanted it to run immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... what about: `stop(true,true)`? See: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
var self = this;
...
this.zoomIn = function() {
  var offset = $("#scrollable").stop(true,true).scrollTop();
  self.increaseZoomLevel(); // Assume this sets the correct zoom level
  var newOffset = offset * self.zoomLevel();
  $("#scrollable").animate({ scrollTop: newOffset });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that the animation needs to complete to make the `scrollTop()` part of `var offset = $("#scrollable").scrollTop()` accurate.

Comment: Well, then you do `var offset = $("#scrollable").stop(true,true).scrollTop();` → stop(*,true) causes the animation to jump to the end. I updated my code already.

Comment: Very nice! But I have all these hidden requirements I didn't express. :) I really want to let the animation complete, or the continuity of the zoom gets chopped up. This is certainly simpler than using the queue, but I think I've figured out a way to use the queue and let all animations complete. +1s for answers that work if continuity of animation isn't important.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of @RobinJonsson's comment, which would be my proposed solution too, using a boolean to allow a new zoom action only after the previous animation is complete:

```
var self = this;
...
this.zooming = false;
this.zoomIn = function() {
    if(!self.zooming){
        self.zooming = true;
        var offset = $("#scrollable").scrollTop();
        self.increaseZoomLevel(); // Assume this sets the correct zoom level
        var newOffset = offset * self.zoomLevel();
        $("#scrollable").animate({ scrollTop: newOffset },function(){
            self.zooming = false;
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I head this at one point, but it would be common for someone to click `zoomIn` a few times in rapid succession. Not processing the clicks that happen while `zooming` is true makes for a feeling of less responsiveness. I suppose I could just count how many times `zoomIn` is called while `zooming` is true and process them myself. But I thought the jQuery queue would handle the serialization of all that for me. The one thing missing here from @RobinJonsson's comment is the "queue the next calculation." I thought that maybe had something to do with jQuery queues.

Comment: +1 for an answer that would work given my initial requirements, though.